# Djongo fails to query BooleanField

Tags: python, django, database, filter, djongo

I have Django application with a module like this:

```py
class myApp(models.Model):
    is_new = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    more_fields = models.TextField(blank=True)
```

And using Djongo for database (which is mongodb)

I can query all fields in the module with no issues, however, when filtering for a boolean field like the following:

```py
    myList = myApp.objects.filter(is_new=False)
        
    for record in myList: ....
```

It fails with the following error:

```
  File "/home/user/myApp/venv/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/djongo/sql2mongo/operators.py", line 258, in evaluate
    self.rhs.negate()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'negate'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/myApp/venv/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/djongo/cursor.py", line 51, in execute
    self.result = Query(
  File "/home/user/myApp/venv/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/djongo/sql2mongo/query.py", line 784, in __init__
    self._query = self.parse()
  File "/home/user/myApp/venv/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/djongo/sql2mongo/query.py", line 885, in parse
    raise exe from e
djongo.exceptions.SQLDecodeError: 

        Keyword: None
        Sub SQL: None
        FAILED SQL: SELECT "mysite_myapp"."more_fields", "mysite_myapp"."is_new" FROM "mysite_myapp" WHERE NOT "mysite_myapp"."is_new"
        Params: ()
        Version: 1.3.6
```

It seems like a Djongo issue unless boolean fields are queried differently

Versions in use:

- Django 3.2.5
- djongo 1.3.6

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This seems to be quite an old issue with Djongo (here is a recent [issue](https://github.com/nesdis/djongo/issues/562) opened about a month ago for the same bug) and people are forced to use a workaround using an `in` lookup:

```
myList = myApp.objects.filter(is_new__in=[False])
```